# Theme header missing in wordpress editor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have used the wordpress theme flatsome in 3 sites. Only in 1 website i could not see and edit the 'theme header' file in the wordpress dashboard. In the other 2 sites, i could see and access the 'theme header' file. Why this could have have happened ? . I myself installed the theme on all 3 sites. Dont understand why this happened.

Comment: You work with a child theme? is there a license key?

Comment: yes . i work with a child theme.

Comment: and it's set on all pages?

Comment: i didnt understand. You meant the theme ? or the license key ?

Comment: is it the same version of the theme? Seems like they have recently rewritten the entire theme

Comment: version of the theme is same for all 3 sites.